How to remove a divider/seprator between each item inside a ForEach View SwiftUI
I am working on auto scroll in swiftUI by using Foreach. Its adding a divider automatically between view that can be seen into the give attached image below.

He is my complete code through you can reproduce the same issue. I have no idea why its showing the divider. I have tried with the following solution but it did't work for Foreach Loop.
Remove top separator line in ListView
import SwiftUI

struct ColorsView: View {
    
    @State private var timer: Timer?
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var closeCount = 0
    
    let colors: [Color] = [
        .red,
        .blue,
        .yellow,
        .brown,
        .green,
        .orange,
        .purple
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                    autoScroller(geometry: geometry)
            }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

// MARK: Color change extension
extension ColorsView {
    
    func autoScroller(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { index in

                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [colors[index % colors.count], colors[(index + 1) % colors.count]]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    .offset(y: offset + CGFloat(index) * geometry.size.height)
                    .listRowInsets(.none)
                
            }
        }
        .animation(.linear(duration: 3), value: offset)
        .onAppear {
            startColorChange(geometry: geometry)
        }
        .onDisappear {
            stopColorChange()
        }
    }
    
    func startColorChange(geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { _ in
            withAnimation {
                
                offset -= geometry.size.height
                if offset <= -geometry.size.height * CGFloat(colors.count) {
                    offset = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stopColorChange() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}

struct ColorsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ColorsView()
    }
}


try removing .listRowInsets(.none)

Usually I would use .listRowSeparator(.hidden) inside a List

@workingdogsupportUkraine I am not using List
